# Subdomain in Azure DNS Zone: CNAME instead of NS

Tags: azure, dns, cname, nameservers

I bought a domain in webs.com (here I'll call it contoso.com) and then I delegated it to my Azure contoso.com Zone DNS. Later I created a subdomain (eg sub.contoso.com) to publish a new website hosted in an Azure VM. For this reason I created a CNAME record to link sub.contoso.com to the Azure VM's default DNS (something like xxxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com). It worked great but after few time I found this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/delegate-subdomain) and, just for a test, I changed my DNS configuration as described by the guide (briefly, I created a new Zone DNS called sub.contoso.com and then I added the NS record in the contoso.com zone). It works but, since I need to create other two subdomains, this configuration seems too complicated and I prefer the previous one. But, and this is my question, I don't understand if the use of the CNAME record with respect to NS leads to some differences in terms of performance or security.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the main difference is that these records are hosting in a separate zone.  One is hosting in the parent zone for the parent domain `contoso.com`, the other is hosting in the children zone for subdomain `sub.contoso.com`. It's convenient to manage the records when there are large records.

> The Domain Name System is a hierarchy of domains. The hierarchy starts
>   from the 'root' domain, whose name is simply '.'. Below this come
>   top-level domains, such as 'com', 'net', 'org', 'uk' or 'jp'. Below
>   these top-level domains are second-level domains, such as 'org.uk' or
>   'co.jp'. And so on. The domains in the DNS hierarchy are hosted using
>   separate DNS zones. These zones are globally distributed, hosted by
>   DNS name servers around the world.
>
> DNS zone - A domain is a unique name in the Domain Name System, for
>   example 'contoso.com'. A DNS zone is used to host the DNS records for
>   a particular domain. For example, the domain 'contoso.com' may contain
>   several DNS records such as 'mail.contoso.com' (for a mail server) and
>   'www.contoso.com' (for a website).

For a normal DNS query process, the records in the parent zone could get answered prefer than the records in the children zone. You could see the DNS query example and [how DNS delegation works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation#how-dns-delegation-works).